# Why does my .gitconfig get written to every time I pull?

Tags: windows, git, git-config

On my Windows box, whenever I execute `git pull` to pull from our Azure DevOps Server instance, my user gitconfig is written to. I can tell because Notepad++ informs me the file has been modified by another program, and indeed the Modified Date is updated. There are no changes to the file.

I would have thought the only git commands that would write to my gitconfig would be `git config` commands. Why do these operations that should be read-only operations modify my gitconfig file?

`git version 2.38.1.windows.1`

Update 1: I tried setting my gitconfig file to read-only, and git still had no problems writing to it.

Update 2: I tried clearing the gitconfig completely, and it added two credential entries, one for my corporate proxy and another for our Azure DevOps server, both with configs of `provider = generic` So it's something to do with the credential store.

Comment: Do you have any hooks installed in your local repository?

Comment: Very few, but this happens no matter which repository I am using, even ones without hooks

Comment: @Nacht Make the file read-only and watch for errors.

Comment: @phd spooky... it still happens! Is git removing the read-only attribute, and then adding it back?? Surely not...

Comment: Git has no problems writing actual config changes to my .gitconfig while it's read-only either.

Comment: Git is not doing this unless it's asked by someone invoking `git config`.  You'll need to figure out what program is rewriting the file or asking Git to do so.

Comment: @phd Aha! I tried to empty my gitconfig, to see if it was trying to add something. I have two credential entries, one for our proxy and one for the Azure DevOps server. When they are missing, they get added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems every time I interacted with any remote (stored on our devops instance), these lines were written to my .gitconfig:

```
[credential "http://ourcorporateproxyurl:8888"]
    provider = generic
[credential "https://ourdevopsurl"]
    provider = generic
```

Answer (score -1):

Ensure that the .gitconfig is in your home folder then rectify it.
This is the global config which is necessary.

Try opening it and see if the file looks like this:

```
[user]
     email = youremail@example.com
     name = Your sweet name
     signingkey = XX26XXXXXXXXXX87

[gpg]
     program = %PATH_OF_GPG

[commit]
    gpgsign = true
```

But everything looks fine,
Try setting global config through command line by;

```
git config --global user.email "MY_NAME@example.com”
```

This command automatically set the .gitconfig in the directory it needed.

You can also follow the Official DOCS to set .gitconfig

Comment: The question is: why `git pull` updates `~/.gitconfig` without `git config` ?